# Как собрать данные с виджета Яндекс.Афиша?

Tags: javascript, html, python, html5

Необходимо получить данные о том сколько билетов куплено на конкретный сеанс. Как можно получить эти данные с виджета Яндекс.Афиша? https://afisha.yandex.ru/moscow/cinema/politseiskii-s-rubliovki-novogodnii-bespredel-2?schedule-preset=today - (виджет который открывается при клике на кнопку со временем начала фильма)

Простым парсингом html не обойтись так как Яндекс использует  (это хорошо видно если посмотреть исходный код страницы)

Как можно достать эти данные? Ну или Если кто знает подскажите более "дружелюбные" в этом плане сервисы)

[image: Вот так выглядит виджет яндекса (купленные билеты - серые точки + билеты могут иметь разную стоимость )]
Вот так выглядит виджет яндекса (купленные билеты - серые точки + билеты могут иметь разную стоимость

Comment: не подскажите где там встречается количество купленных билетов?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку с временем сеанса открывается виджет. На нем можно видеть какие билеты можно купить а какие уже проданы(они отображаются серыми кружками). https://afisha.yandex.ru/moscow/cinema/places/piat-zviozd-na-novokuznetskoi?place-schedule-preset=today - более хороший пример - фильм звездные воины. 

Нужно получить какие места проданы и по какой цене.

Comment: почти не разбираюсь в requests, но по-моему можно отправить post, а не get запрос, а содержимое уже этого спарсить, или я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Исследуя этот вопрос я понял что <svg> в html5 внутри - это что то похожее на xml и что как то можно получить к нему доступ через javascript. Но как конкретно это можно сделать я не нашел и не придумал.

В идеале нужно получить следующее : сколько билетов были поданы на конкретный сеанс и по какой цене (на один сеанс билеты могут стоить по разному)

Comment: Прасинг осуществляю через SELENIUM 

Но конкретно им не могу каким либо образом спарсить эти данные так так svg - это картинка